# In Azure Mobile Services App using attribute routing throws Key already added excetion

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I keep getting the exception **An item with the same key has already been added.** at `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` in a project that has worked for sometime I cannot determine what has changed.

I removed all my controllers save for one and it throws with or without attributes present.

I removed my CORS setting - same result and kept removing everything until the bare bones code below and it still throws.

I have updated all packages with and without -reinstall

here is my webapiconfig

```
 public static void Register( )
    {
        var options = new ConfigOptions();
        var config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));
        //config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        //config.SetIsHosted(true);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    }
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

In a moment of 2AM desperation I commented out `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`and it worked.

I must have commented it out earlier in the process and when I started the maintenance I enable it.

AZMO must turn it on by default.